# Use the alternating series test to determine if $\frac{x^{3k}}{2^k}$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

There is no $(-1)^k$ how do I know that this is an alternating series? In fact the series is always positive. It appears that as $k \to \infty$ the sequence $a_k \to 0$

$$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{x^{3k}}{2^k}$$

Answer (score 0):

It is always positive of x greater than 0.
If x is negative, you can rewrite the series as
$\sum_{k=0}^n \frac{(-1)^k|x|^{3k}}{2^k}$